# using unzip within PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, unzip

Every night we need to zip certain files contained in a folder.  I then need to make sure that all the files that should have been zipped are in the zip file.
I have created a piece of code that work perfectly on my PC but when I move the code to the live server I get the following error:-

The term 'unzip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet'

I have installed dot.net 4.5 & also the PowerShell Community Extensions 3.1

Here is my code that creates an array of file names:-

```
$UnZip_Test = unzip -t $ZipFile
$zip_contents = $UnZip_Test | ? { $_ -match "^\s*testing:\s*(.*?)\s+OK\s*$"} | % { $matches[1] }
```

Comment: Use the [`Get-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849711.aspx) cmdlet on your own workstation to find out where `unzip` is defined.

Comment: This resulted in resolving the problem.

Answer (score 4):

unzip is not the cmd-let Community Extensions uses. If you had correctly installed the PCE 3.1 you should be able to use  `Expand-Archive` cmdlet.

```
expand-archive -format zip -path $ZipFile
```

Comment: Command is just `expand-archive -path $ZipFile` now

Answer (score 2):

`unzip` is not a PowerShell built-in command. You need to provide an `unzip.exe` in one of the folders in the `$env:PATH` on the production server, or define a function/cmdlet or alias that does The Right Thing™.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my powershell scripts, granted it's not powershell but requires java to be installed.

```
jar xf ./path/to/archive.zip
```

In my case, knowing java is on a server is a lot easier than downloading some community extension all over the place